# Enumeration Reflection

Tags: reflection, foreach, d, enumeration

Does D provide some way of reflecting on the values of an enumeration, say `e`, typically iterating over each of its values a bit similar to `.tupleof` for structs and classes. I guess we could always do

```
foreach (val; e.min..e.max)
```

but what about non-continuous enumerations? And enumerations are inclusive on max-value but ranges are not.

**Update**: I just discovered: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#.EnumMembers

I believe this all we need right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std.traits.EnumMembers` can do it, and so can `__traits(allMembers,YourEnum)`.

`foreach(value, name; EnumMembers!YourEnum) { }` sounds like what you want.

Comment: Couldn't this foreach-behaviour be builtin to the language, having needing to use `EnumMembers`?

Comment: Maybe, though it is a bit more consistent how it is now: foreach goes over a tuple or array rather than a type, then __traits(allMembers) returns a tuple of names, and __traits(getMember) lets you get the details. That works the same way on modules, classes, and structs too, which don't always have a simple answer for what value would be.

Comment: What about combining these with std.algorithms such as `map` or `join`? From what I can see in my test this is not possible because these reflected structures live in compile-time right? The only thing kind I have found possible to do with them is to index and `foreach` them.

Comment: If you put square brackets around it, you'll get an array: `[EnumMembers!Test]` which can be passed to other things. These things, and the allMembers traits, return a compile time tuple, which is basically an argument list; it is similar to the result being code expressions literally separated by commas. So if you pass it to a function, it expands to fill the arguments. And that same effect works in an array literal too. Check it out here: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/arraytuples.d and note the square brackets around the usage to form the array to pass to map.